# Error with converting list item to integer

Tags: python

I am trying to pass class element to method. Element is formed dynamically inserting current time in it. Mine class looks something like this:

```
class MineContact(dict):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        # set your default values
        import time
        curr_time = repr(time.time()).replace('.', '') 
        self['tel'] = [{
            'type': ['Mobile'],
            'value': '555%s' % curr_time[8:]}]
        ...
```

So, I create object of this class and now I want to insert it as method argument:

```
contact = MineContact()
extra_text = "-%d" % (self.iteration)
new_contact.insert_phone(contact.tel['value'])
```

When I run this script, I get this type of error:

> TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

So, does anyone knows where am I getting it wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a list of one dictionary `[{}]` instead of `{}`. The following will work:

```
contact = MineContact()
extra_text = "-%d" % (self.iteration)
new_contact.insert_phone(contact.tel[0]['value'])
```

Alternatively, you could change your `self['tel']` to a dictionary instead of a list of a dictionary. Here is what it would look like:

```
self['tel'] = {'type': ['Mobile'], 'value': '555%s' % curr_time[8:]}
```

Then, your original `new_contact.insert_phone(contact.tel['value'])` would work